# JavaScript `this` works different in different class methods

Tags: javascript, class, d3.js, this

I "warp" d3 drag code inside class and have a problem with `this` when I try to use class fields in different class methods.

Here a code:

```
'use strict';

class D3DragHandler {

    constructor(link, datas) {
        this.drag = null;
        this.links = link;
        this.datas = datas;
        this.zadragged = null;
        //        console.log(this.link);
    }

    saveNodePosition() {

        var postData = {};
        var adragged = this.zadragged; //ERROR HERE

        postData.id = datas[adragged].id;
        postData.x = datas[adragged].dx + datas[adragged].x;
        postData.y = datas[adragged].dy + datas[adragged].y;

        d3.xhr('/index.php?option=com_myrod&task=ajax.save&format=json&raw=true&token=' + token + "&data=" + JSON.stringify({
                "data": postData
            }))
        .header("Content-Type", "application/json")
        .post("",
            function (err, rawData) {
            var data = JSON.parse(rawData);
            console.log("got response", data);
        });

    }

    setDragged(value) {
        console.log(value);
        this.zadragged = value; //ERROR HERE
        //var v = this.zadragged;
    }

    init() {
        var link = this.links;
        var datas = this.datas;
        var saveFunc = this.saveNodePosition;

        var draggedKeyFunc = this.setDragged;

        // Define drag beavior
        this.drag = d3.behavior.drag()
            .on("drag", function (d) {
                var x = d3.event.x;
                var y = d3.event.y;

                d3.select(this).attr("transform", "translate(" + x + "," + y + ")");

                //adragged = d.key;
                draggedKeyFunc(d.key);

                datas[d.key].dx = d3.event.x;
                datas[d.key].dy = d3.event.y;
                link.update();

            })
            .origin(function () {
                var t = d3.transform(d3.select(this).attr("transform"));

                svg.select("text.position").text(function (d) {
                    return Math.round(d.value.x) + ":" + Math.round(d.value.y);
                })

                return {
                    x: t.translate[0],
                    y: t.translate[1]
                };

            })
            .on("dragend", function () {
                var d = d3.event.sourceEvent;

                console.log(d);

                saveFunc(d);
            });
        return this.drag;
    }

}
```

I make comments in code to show where I get errors, and it is very strange, because I use `this` in other methods and it works just fine. But in this strings I get error:

`TypeError: this is undefined`

It is very strange, I expect that all code must work same way, but maybe I did miss something here?

`setDragged(value)` method is class method so i expect that `this` is class itself.

Comment: When you assign functions to variables the `this` context becomes the global context.  It's okay to assign `this` to a var that is used inside another function. Just access the method on the var from within the other function.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Your problem is that class methods are not bound to any specific object, so `this` refers to whatever object they were called as a method of, so when you this:

```
var draggedKeyFunc = this.setDragged;

// ... 

draggedKeyFunc(d.key);
```

That object association is gone, and `this` is `undefined` in strict mode, or the global object outside of strict mode.

Options include calling the object as a method:

```
var dragHandler = this;

// ... 

dragHandler.draggedKeyFunc(d.key);
```

Or creating a bound function:

```
var draggedKeyFunc = this.setDragged.bind(this);

// ... 

draggedKeyFunc(d.key);
```

Comment: Thanks Alexander i get it now, i use `.bind(this);` and all worked.

Answer (score 0):

You can use class property like below, if you include babel plugin in your build process

```
setDragged = (value) => {
    console.log(value);
    this.zadragged = value; //ERROR HERE
}
```